# When does the "reject" string have an empty reject reason upon submitting a new block?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

I submitted a new block using the rpc command `submit`. And I just got a "reject" string without a reject reason.

I checked the bitcoind source code, and found that it usually sends a reject reason; bitcoind would only omit a reason if the `strRejectReason` is empty. Why and when would the `strRejectReason` be empty?

```
static Value BIP22ValidationResult(const CValidationState& state)
{
    if (state.IsValid())
        return Value::null;

    std::string strRejectReason = state.GetRejectReason();
    if (state.IsError())
        throw JSONRPCError(RPC_VERIFY_ERROR, strRejectReason);
    if (state.IsInvalid())
    {
        if (strRejectReason.empty())
            return "rejected"; // The value that gets returned
        return strRejectReason;
    }
    // Should be impossible
    return "valid?";
}
```

[Source.](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/f914f1a746d7f91951c1da262a4a749dd3ebfa71/src/rpcmining.cpp#L302)

Comment: Are you using the command `submit` (which doesn't exist, I think) the command `submitblock`, or `getblocktemplate` with the mode argument set to `proposal`?

Comment: Does the source of `CValidationState::GetRejectReason` have anything useful?

Comment: Which version of the source code? There have been recent changes in this area.